# How to implement section access data level security in Qlik Sense

Tags: qliksense

I want to show/filter data according to location and user levels. 
mapping will be location to location with `User`.

dataset will be like :

[image: dataset image]

Now, if you can see the location hierarchy is like say lower to upper:
Beed -- jalgaon--yawatmal--pune--maharashtra

Location Jalgaon has two childs means 
When Dharmesh(level1) will login he should be able to view the data of only jalgaon and Beed.
When Mahesh(level1) will login he should be able to view the data of jalagon and nagpur.

When nikhil logs in he should be able to view data of his lower levels i.e Pune yawatmal, jalgaon, nagpur and beed along with users data.
NOTE: if at all any user quites and that field is NULL then also his higher level user can see his data. Ex: if Mahesh is left blank then also nikhil should be able see data of both mahesh and dharmesh.

Can anyone please help me with suggestions how i can achieve this in qlik sense section access? How could be my table structure and section access sheet, any scripts?
Any suggestion or help are highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have fix number of levels?